# Why does my ViewController dismiss on its own?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, segue

I have two viewcontroller one that records video and the second one that plays the recorded video. The problem Im having is that when I press on the stop record button the seconds view controller pops up but dismisses on its own. It only plays the recorded video for one second and then dismisses. Why is that happening? Im using a segue from my first VC to the second VC.

```
 //First VC
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    let vc = segue.destination as! VideoPlaybackViewController
    vc.videoURL = sender as? URL
}


func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    
        let videoRecorded = self.outputURL! as URL
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: videoRecorded)

        
        
    //UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path, nil, nil, nil)
}



 //second vc

  class VideoPlaybackViewController: UIViewController {


let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
var videoURL: URL!
@IBOutlet weak var videoPlayBack: UIView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        videoPlayBack.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
    
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL as URL)
        avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    
        avPlayer.play()
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to , but i am giving an idea . Have you tried event.stopPropagation() in c# syntax ? I think that the event propagates to the other view since they are linked together

Comment: I figured it out it had something to do with my alertView. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out I had a `AlertViewController` that was automatically getting dismissed and I guess when I ran the `performSegue` the second ViewController was getting dismissed as well. Here is the code for the AlertView

```
        let  alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Video saved to photo library!", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        let dismissInSeconds = DispatchTime.now() + 1.0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dismissInSeconds){
        alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            

    }
```